# CSCore - Play audio from MemoryStream

Tags: memorystream, wasapi, cscore

I am new to CsCore. Need some help. I want to build an Audio Recorder, which is able to record mic and Speakers into a file and an external Recorder device. I have successfully finished recording to file. Now I want just the same thing once again, but playing on a certain audio speaker device. I thought of piping into a stream and using this stream as source for a WasapiOut. However, I failed connecting this stream to an IWaveSource.

```
private Stream _strm;
private WaveWriter _waveWriterFile;
private WaveWriter _wavewriterStream;
private WasapiOut _externalRecorder;

_strm = new MemoryStream();
_wavewriterStream = new WaveWriter(_strm, _SpkCapture.WaveFormat);
IWaveSource ws = new WaveFileReader(_strm);
_externalRecorder.Initialize(ws);
_externalRecorder.Play();

// on Event I do following:
_waveWriterFile.Write(e.Data, e.Offset, e.ByteCount);
_wavewriterStream.Write(e.Data, e.Offset, e.ByteCount);
```

Everything works fine until I call 'new WaveFileReader(_strm);'. I get an exception (translated from me) "cannot read beyond end of stream". The stream contains data at this point of time. Have 100ms sleep before trying to fetch the stream. I have also tried

```
IWaveSource ws = new CSCore.MediaFoundation.MediaFoundationDecoder(strm);
```

But no luck. I really need help.

Comment: I would also be glad, if there is an option outside of Memorystream or even cscore to play raw wav data on a specific Speaker device

Comment: What kind of format is the data inside of the memorystream?